# Calculated column- evaluating multiple conditions

Tags: calculated-column

Banged my head against this one for too long so thought I'd give in and post it. I'm trying to create a calculated column that evaluates two different conditions, as in:

IF

[Boolean A] = No

OR

[Boolean A] = Yes AND [Text B] is not null AND [Text C] is not null

THEN

return "READY"

ELSE

return "NOT READY"

Possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why test Boolean A is no or yes? Did you mean to have another Boolean in there? Or is it that Boolean A may be null?

Comment: These are coming from an InfoPath form and the logic is this: if the boolean (Special Approval Required) is NO then I want to set a Ready for Approval column to READY, but if the boolean is YES then I have to wait for two signatures on the InfoPath form. Make sense? It's perfectly likely that there's other logic that will get this done, just haven't found a more obvious solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try. Just based on your input as I don't have this mapped out anywhere to test:

=IF(OR([Boolean A]='No', [Boolean A]='Yes'), IF(AND(LEN[Text B] > 0, LEN[Text C] > 0), "READY", "NOT READY"))

Maybe this is better!

=IF(OR([Boolean A]='No', AND([Boolean A]='Yes', AND(LEN[Text B] > 0, LEN[Text C] > 0)), "READY", "NOT READY"))

Comment: Your comment got cutoff when I viewed the last time so this is slightly off!

Comment: Testing now, looks close but throwing syntax errors. Usually just a misplaced parenthesis but so far I don't see it. The formula with my real column names included and the boolean conditions changed to = FALSE and = TRUE (that's the only foolproof boolean expression I've found) appears below. =IF(OR([Req_VM]=FALSE, AND([Req_VM]=TRUE, AND(LEN[Storage_Sign] > 0, LEN[VMWare_Sign] > 0)), "READY", "NOT READY"))

Comment: By the way, a Thank You should have been in there somewhere, so... Thank You!

Comment: Well spevilgenius lives up to his name, though possibly minus the "evil". Many thanks! This answer got me almost all the way there and I finished it by deconstructing the formula, first testing the AND and LEN arguments and working outward from there. The final result should you want to know is: =IF(OR([Boolean A]=FALSE,AND([Boolean A]=TRUE,LEN([Text B])>0,LEN([Text C])>0)),"READY","NOT READY")

Answer (score 0):

The boolean field is notated w/o Yes/No, just use this:

```
 =IF([BooleanField],"true text","false text")
```