# Creating a Status column (IF statement/calculated column)

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I'm developing list for managing a project with 11 columns each representing a project milestone.

We'll call them A,B,C...K.

"A" representing a status of "Project Started" and K representing "Project Complete" with various statuses in between.

When a milestone has been reached, the date is input into the appropriate column. So when the project is complete, there will be dates in all columns A-K

I wish to incorporate a new column that indicates the current status depending on if columns A-K have been filled in.

So if all columns are blank, a status of "Awaiting start" is indicated.

If column A is filled in with a date, a status of "A" is indicated.

If columns A and column B are filled in then a status of "B" is indicated.

If columns A, B and C are filled in then a status of "C" is indicated.
*
*
If all the columns are filled in with dates, a status of "K" is indicated.

[image: diagram]

Any ideas? Some form of If statement in a calculated Status column?

Answer (score 6):

You can try If statement in calculated column like

```
IF([Status]="On Track","1",IF([Status]="Concern but Plan in place", "2", IF([Status]="Open need Plan", "3", "0")))
```

Column blank check you can perform as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([My Column]),"EMPTY",[My Column])
```

For multiple checks:

[Calculated column- evaluating multiple conditions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45513/calculated-column-evaluating-multiple-conditions)

In this way you can build your formula.

Comment: use semi column  (;) instead of comma if it gives syntax error for if. https://egilhansen.com/2013/02/14/sharepoints-formula-syntax-can-change-depending-on-a-sites-regional-setting/