# Calculated column - calculate percentage done based on status

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to create a calculated column based on a status column. If the status is "planned", I'd like it to return 5%, if it is "writing", it should be 30%, if "technical review" it should be 50%, etc...

I have had luck with this formula:

```
=IF(  OR([Status]="Planned",[Status]="Writing")  , "5" , "30" )
```

But when I try to add more than the two statuses, I get the Error page.
Does anyone have any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong. I have tried many different methods but none seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below function hope it will help with multiple if condition

```
=IF([Status]="planned","5",IF([Status]="writing", "30", IF([Status]="technical review", "50")))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF([Status]="On Track","1",IF([Status]="Concern but Plan in place", "2", IF([Status]="Open need Plan", "3", "0")))
```

Column blank check you can perform as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([My Column]),"EMPTY",[My Column])
```

For multiple checks:

[Calculated column- evaluating multiple conditions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45513/calculated-column-evaluating-multiple-conditions)

In this way you can build your formula.

Answer (score 1):

```
 =IF(OR([Status]="Planned",[Status]="Writing"),"5","30")
```

Does not really do what you might think, it does (*in human language*):

```
 IF Status IS "Planned" OR "Writing" THEN 5    ELSE 30
```

You can accept Bhaskar answer, so he receives the points..

Reformatted it reads better (and cou can copy/paste it like this, SharePoint will ignore linebreaks and redundant spaces, I usually prepare a Formula in Notepad)

```
 =IF([Status]="planned" , "5"
     ,IF([Status]="writing" , "30"
         ,IF([Status]="technical review" , "50"
            )
        )
     )
```

Couple of notes:

- SharePoint only allows for **7** nested IF statements; you have to rework your formula if you need more nested checks.
- The last IF has no ELSE clause, valid coding, but be aware SharePoint will make that a (default) FALSE value (for any status not mentioned in the IFs)

#### Update re: comments

You can not nest more than 7 levels **deep**

So you have to built Formulas like:

```
IF ( OR( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 )
    , IF ( 1 
            , Do One
            , IF ( 2 
                , Do Two
                ...
    , IF ( 7
        , Do Seven
        , IF( 8
            , Do Eight
            ...
```

Comment: Oh wow!!! It works. Thank you so much for helping me with this!

If I want to add more clauses, can I start a new formula? (I have more than 7 statuses)

Comment: Calculated Columns does not allow more than 7 Nested IFs. If you have more than 7 status in that case you can join two nested IF formulae with "&".

Comment: This did not work. I got an error.
I added this to the end:
&
=IF([Status]="Planned" , "5"
     ,IF([Status]="Pending" , "0"
         ,IF([Status]="On hold" , "0"
                                
          )
     )
)